# Post a public message in Facebook with FB.api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have tried to post a message on my wall using FB.api(). I posted it successfully but it's showing only for me. I want to make this post public.
In app Configuring permissions i set "Default Activity Privacy" value Public but still message posting private.
I tried to do it by following code:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {                    
                var privacy = { 'value': 'EVERYONE' };
                var txt = 'my post to test feed post using api';
                FB.api('me/feed', 'post', { message: txt, privacy: privacy }, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                    } else {
                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, { scope: 'email,user_likes,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_stream' });
```

Please check my code.

Answer (score 0):

As said in reference 'privacy' field value should be string.
Try to pass "{ 'value': 'EVERYONE' }" as string, not an object.